# Use alias table in MySQL query without creating a VIEW

Tags: mysql, sql

How I could make the following code work without creating a `VIEW` using MySQL 5.6.43?

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS sla_calculation;
CREATE VIEW sla_calculation AS SELECT clock FROM service_alarms WHERE (serviceid = 473) AND
        (clock >= get_unix_init_clock(30, 'day'));


SELECT sla1.clock - sla2.clock AS failure_time
FROM sla_calculation AS sla1
LEFT JOIN sla_calculation AS sla2
    ON sla2.clock = (
        SELECT MAX(clock)
        FROM sla_calculation AS sla3
        WHERE sla3.clock < sla1.clock
    )
ORDER BY sla1.clock
```

I don't want to create a `VIEW` because this query will be inside a function (not to mention that it will have variables within `WHERE`). I've, unsuccessfully, tried the following query (receiving Error Code 1146: `Table 'test.sla1' doesn't exist`):

```
SELECT sla1.clock - sla2.clock AS failure_time
FROM
    (
        SELECT clock
        FROM service_alarms
        WHERE (serviceid = 473) AND
            (clock >= get_unix_init_clock(30, 'day'))
    ) AS sla1
    LEFT JOIN sla1 AS sla2
        ON sla2.clock = (
            SELECT MAX(clock)
            FROM sla1 AS sla3
            WHERE sla3.clock < sla1.clock
        )
ORDER BY sla1.clock
```

Another option would be to use the `LAG()` function (thanks @Gordon Linoff and @Bill Karwin for the insight), but, unfortunately, it's only natively available from MySQL 8.

```
SELECT clock - LAG(clock) OVER s AS failure_time
FROM service_alarms
WHERE (serviceid = 473) AND (clock >= get_unix_init_clock(30, 'day'))
WINDOW s AS (ORDER BY clock)
```

I understand that I can't use an alias in the `FROM` clause and I'm unable to use the `LAG()` funciton, so how can I work this around? Thanks a lot!

Table Schema:
[image: Table Schema:]

Comment: Can you share table schema?

Comment: @Pals I just edited the question with this information.

Comment: The better question is why are you still not on MySQL 8?  It's been out for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `lag()`:

```
SELECT clock - LAG(clock, 1) ORDER BY (clock)
FROM service_alarms sa
WHERE (serviceid = 473) AND
      (clock >= get_unix_init_clock(30, 'day')
ORDER BY clock;
```

This assumes that `clock` has unique values.  If not, there are similar constructs but they are a little more complicated.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using an older version (5.6.43) without `LAG` natively supported. I forgot to mention that and I'll update the question. Should I simulate the `LAG` function or something? And yes, `clock` has unique values.

Answer (score 0):

The alternatives all require MySQL 8.0.

- Using a [Window Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) like `LAG()` as Gordon Linoff suggests.
- Using a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), you can create a kind of "just-in-time" view, so you can reference a derived table more than once, including joining it to itself.
- Using [LATERAL JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html) allows a derived table to reference tables preceding it in the join.

If you aren't using MySQL 8.0 yet, then I think you're stuck with using a view.

Comment: So assuming the impossibility to create a `VIEW` inside a function, I'm unable to perform this?

Comment: You can't use CREATE VIEW (or any DDL statement or any other type of statement that causes an implicit commit) inside a stored function. But you can do that inside a stored procedure. Or you can do CREATE VIEW via any other client API that runs SQL statements. I don't know why you would need to put it inside a stored function.

Comment: I hardly ever use or recommend to implement code in MySQL stored functions or stored procedures. I wrote up some reasons for this here: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-reasons-not-to-use-or-not-use-stored-procedures/answer/Bill-Karwin

Comment: Is this what you need ?
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kVNirKPqkAUQXsjBTPQZRz/1

Comment: @BillKarwin I need to put it inside a function because I'll need a different `VIEW` every time I call the function (two times, with different parameters passed to `get_unix_init_clock()`, every 10 seconds to each `service_id`). My final goal is to use the result of this function in a `Grafana` button for each `service_id`. That's basically why I need a stored function and can't use any API. Do you have any other suggestions? :)

Comment: @Pals unfortunately no :(. With your example the `failure_time` column should have the values 0 (or `null`, doens't matter actually), 3 and 2. `failure_time` basically represents the diffence between two consecutive rows of the alias table.

Comment: My suggestion is to upgrade to MySQL 8.0 if you need features of MySQL 8.0.